# Elements in $F=\bigcup \limits_{n=1}^\infty \left(\bigcap \limits_{k=n}^\infty E_k\right)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, limsup-and-liminf

let S be set with subsets $ E_1,E_2,E_3,....$ Show that:

a) $F=\bigcup \limits_{n=1}^\infty \left(\bigcap \limits_{k=n}^\infty E_k\right)$ consists of all elements of S each of which belongs to all but a finite number of $E_j$.

b) $G=\bigcap \limits_{n=1}^\infty \left(\bigcup \limits_{j=n}^\infty E_j\right)$ consists of all elements of S each of which belongs to infinitely many $E_k$.

Comment: I no this rather easy question but damn me i am not able to solve it

Comment: A I think about it (not to be taken as a proof!) is to consider reading (a) with union as "or" and intersection as "and." 

Suppose $x \in F$. This means that $x \in \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty E_k$ (e.g. $x$ is in $E_1$ and $E_2$ and $E_3$ and $\ldots$), OR that $x \in \bigcap_{k=2}^\infty E_k$ (e.g. $x$ is in $E_2$ and $E_3$ and $E_4$ and $\dots$) OR $\ldots$ 

So, that means, for some $n$, $x$ is in all the sets from $E_n$ "on up." (b) is read similarly (especially if you consider its compliment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straight-forward way to approach this is to show that $x \in F$ or $G$ if and only if it satisfies the conditions described, treating both directions of implication separately.

For example, for $F$:  suppose that $x$ appears in all but finitely many $E_j$. Then there is an $n$ such that $x \in E_j$ whenever $j\geq n$. It follows that 
$ x \in \bigcap_{k=n}^\infty E_k$. It follows that $x \in F$.

Now, suppose that $x$ does not satisfy this condition. Then, there is an infinite sequence of sets $\{E_{n_k}\}$ such that $x \notin E_{n_k}$ (or, if you prefer: for every $n$, there is a $k\geq n$ such that $x \notin E_k$). It follows that for every $n$,
$ x \notin \bigcap_{k=n}^\infty E_k$. We may therefore state $x \notin F$.

The description of $G$ can be proven in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 2):

If $x\in F$, then $x$ is element of one of the sets that are forming the union $F$, therefore $x\in \cap_{k = n}^\infty E_k$ for at least one $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Because $x$ is the element of the intersecion $\cap_{k = n}^\infty E_k$, $x$ is element of every $E_k$ where $k\geq n$. One can conclude that $x$ may be "missing" only in the first $n-1$ sets, which is a finite number.

Analogically for b).

Answer (score 1):

As to a): $x \in F$ iff there exists some $n(x)$ such that for all $k \ge n(x)$, $x \in E_k$. So $x$ is in eventually all (except maybe the first $n(x)$ many) $E_k$...

As to b): $x \in G$ iff for every $n$ there exists some $j \ge n$ such that $x \in E_j$, so we can always find "new" indices $j$ such that $E_j$ contains $x$.